# Github actions build docker image when there are changes in folder

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, github-actions, cicd

Net project. I have multiple projects running and all projects are dockerized. currently I am using matrix statergy to build all the docker files. Here I want to change my implementation. I have many projects/services so whenever there is change I do not want to build and deploy all the projects/services but i want to deploy specific project/service. So I am looking for the folder change approach. So whenever there is change in folder I am planning to build only that projet/service.

Below is my current approach using matrix

```
build-and-push-image:
    name: "BUILD: ${{ matrix.name }}"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: prep
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJson(needs.prep.outputs.matrix)}}
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ matrix.docker-image-name }}
          flavor: latest=true
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=pr
            type=semver,pattern={{version}}
      - name: Restore dependencies
        shell: bash
        run: dotnet restore
        
      - name: Build and push Docker image ${{ matrix.name }}
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: ${{matrix.context }}
          file: ${{ matrix.dockerfile }}
          push: true
          tags: ${{ matrix.docker-image-name }}:${{ github.sha }}
```

Using this approach it builds all the dockerfiles but i want to build and deploy specific project/service when there is change. So how Can I do this? Or is there any good approach to handle this? Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that we have a repository like:

```
.
├── .github
│   └── workflows
│       └── matrix_depend_on_changes.yml
├── .gitignore
├── proj1
│   └── test1.txt
├── proj2
│   └── test2.txt
└── proj3
    └── test3.txt
```

If any file of `proj1` directory is changed we have to build `docker-image-1` image. Same with `proj2` and `proj3`. If no changes in `proj1` then `docker-image-1` build should be skipped.

In this case `matrix_depend_on_changes.yml` may be looks like:

````yaml
---
name: 'triggered on PUSH'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - your_brunch_name

jobs:
  get_with_predefined_action:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
      pull-requests: read

    steps:
      # Way is recommended by the Internet
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get changed files with predefined action
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v37
  
      - name: List all changed files
        run: |
          echo '# FILES with tj-actions/changed-files' >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          echo '' >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          echo '```' >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"

          for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}; do
            echo "$file was changed" >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          done

          echo '```' >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"

  get_manually:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
      pull-requests: read
    outputs:
      IMAGES_TO_BUILD: ${{ steps.set_images.outputs.IMAGES_TO_BUILD }}
    steps:
      # Dirty way (Personally I like it)
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get changed files manually
        run: |
          files_list="$(git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }} HEAD | xargs)"
          echo '# Files with git command' >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          echo '' >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          echo '```' >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"

          for file in ${files_list}; do
            echo "$file was changed" >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"
          done

          echo '```' >> "${GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY}"

          # save files into variable
          printf 'THE_FILES=%s\n' "${files_list}" >> "${GITHUB_ENV}"

      # Since output of tj-actions/changed-files and 
      - name: Get docker image names
        # I'm familiar with python so will use it to parse file names
        # be careful if you have spaces into file names
        shell: python
        env:
          PROJECT_IMAGE_MAP: '{"proj1": "docker-image-1", "proj2": "docker-image-2", "proj3": "docker-image-3"}'
        run: |
          from os import environ
          import json
          
          # split files string into list. Divide by spaces
          files = environ.get("THE_FILES").split(' ')
          proj_image_map = json.loads(environ.get("PROJECT_IMAGE_MAP"))

          images = []

          # check if proj1, proj2, etc is a part of changed file path
          for file in files:
            for k, v in proj_image_map.items():
              if k in file:
                if v not in images:
                  images.append(v)

          # save retreived images as json array
          with open(environ.get("GITHUB_ENV"), 'a') as f:
            f.write('IMAGES_TO_BUILD=' + json.dumps(images) + '\n')
      
      - name: Set image names as output for matrix
        id: set_images
        run: |
          echo "IMAGES_TO_BUILD=${IMAGES_TO_BUILD}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  print_image_names_with_matrix:
    name: "Build image: ${{ matrix.image }}"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: get_manually
    strategy:
      matrix:
        image: ${{ fromJson( needs.get_manually.outputs.IMAGES_TO_BUILD ) }}

    steps:
      - name: Print image name from matrix
        run: |
          echo "${{ matrix.image }}"
````

Here is `get_with_predefined_action` and `get_manually` jobs are doing the same stuff. Checking for changed files. However, I don't like to use [third party actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/changed-files) that may be written in couple of lines manually, so I chose second one to get files using `git` command. Steps `Get docker image names` and `Set image names as output for matrix` may be used with both types of jobs above.

I'm using `PROJECT_IMAGE_MAP` environment variable to associate folder names with image names. And `IMAGES_TO_BUILD` output will be used to build exact images (Of course it is a sample and Docker image names are just printed out)

Finally if I change `proj1/test1.txt` and `proj3/test3.txt` files and push new commit, Summary will be looks like:

---

## FILES with tj-actions/changed-files

```
proj1/test1.txt was changed
proj3/test3.txt was changed
```

## Files with git command

```
proj1/test1.txt was changed
proj3/test3.txt was changed
```

And workflow is looking like:

[image]

[image]

I hope that is expected behavior.

## Warning:

Be careful with files with spaces. Something like `/home/User Folder` will be splitted into two paths `/home/User` and `Folder`. You should consider to fix logic of `Get changed files manually` and `Get docker image names` steps if you plan to use files with spaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Lets say there is a change in  proj1 so i need to build only proj1 this works as per above code. I would like to deploy manifest ymls after build. so where can i include this?

Comment: I don't know what mean `deploy manifest ymls` and how it suppose to work. So can't do exact answer. Teoretically it shold be an extra step after image build step? I don't know `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: yes extra step. For example if you build project1 then you need to deploy that image to kubernets so what i was asking is where exactly that step we can have?

Comment: Probably it should be next step after `Print image name from matrix` step in my example (if we agree that `Print image ...` is an example-like simple representation of image build process)